# Single app mode in my iOS application

Tags: ios, configuration-profile, apple-configurator

I want to implement Single app mode in my iOS application through coding. For this I am doing the following steps:

1. I am supervising my device through apple configurator and using config profile generated by configurator itself.
2. I have selected the restriction payload to generate my profile because I want single app mode functionality.
3. According to apple documentation one key is added in Restriction payload that is “autonomousSingleAppModePermittedAppIDs” in iOS and later. But I am not able to find it anywhere to fill my bundle identifier. I have tried to add this key manually by editing the profile in text edit but this process invalidates my profile.

Here is the link reference:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW13

Under the Restrictions Payload section of the documentation.

4. I have tried to generate my profile with the help of iPCU (iPhone Configuration Utility) as well but did not find anything.

So please help me out what I am missing here or what else I need to do.

Thanks
Harish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This key is available in the configuration profile settings of MDM solutions such as [Meraki](https://meraki.cisco.com/products/systems-manager).

You will also need to distribute the configuration profile through MDM in order for Single App Mode to work on the device.